# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14' error de sintaxis

Tags: sql, sql-server, ajax, asp.net, oledb

Buen día, después de intentar un buen rato encontrar el error recurro a uds.
este es el query en backend que me da el error:

```
else if  Consulta = 3 then
sSel = "Insert into Permisos (id_usr, id_depto, id_page) " & _
"values  ((SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('usuarios')) ,"&id_depto&" ,"&page&"  )"
Set rst = conn.Execute(sSel)
conn.Close()
Set rst = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
END IF
```

esta es la URL que envía los datos para la query:

```
nuevo_usuarioback.asp?depto=1&page=0&consulta=3
```

y el error cuando se ejecuta el query es:

```
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e14'

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','.

/indicadores/nuevo_usuarioback.asp, lï¿½nea 46
```

ya probé el query en SQL server y funciona sin errores, pero en código me dice que hay error en la sintaxis y realmente yo no lo veo.

Comment: ¿Has revisado la cadena después de concatenar los valores? Tu código tiene un problema importante ya que está abierto a inyección de SQL. Es importante que aprendas a parametrizar tus consultas para evitarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Resuelto, al final era un problema de una de las variables `id_depto` en realidad debería ser `depto` la confusión nació por que tenia declarada ambas variables y mandaba a llamar una sin valores (null) entonces ahi era el problema